# Line integral of two intersecting spheres

Tags: integration

How can I find the length of the line formed by two intersecting unit spheres shifted a distance x from each other? Any suggestions to approaching the problem is also greatly appreciate! Thanks!

Comment: The intersection is a circle, not a line.

Comment: Yes, I mean the circumference of the circle that is formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form a system with the implicit equations of the spheres
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=r_0^2,\\(x-d)^2+y^2+z^2=r_1^2.$$
(Note that I used $d$ instead of your $x$.)

Subtracting an equation from the other, the other turns to the plane of support of the circle.
$$2dx-d^2=r_0^2-r_1^2,$$
or 
$$x=\frac{r_0^2-r_1^2+d^2}{2d}.$$
and this gives you the equation of the circle,
$$y^2+z^2=r_0^2-x^2=r^2.$$
In case of two unit spheres (radius $\frac12$), $r=\frac12\sqrt{1-d^2}$.

Then you turn this into a parametric equation
$$y=r\cos\theta\\z=r\sin\theta,$$
and use the classical integral of the arc element. Should yield $2\pi r$.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use an integral.  Looking at the cross section gives a right triangle whose hypotenuse is $1$ (distance from the center of a sphere to a point of intersection), whose base is $\frac{x}{2}$ (distance from center of sphere to center of circle of intersection), and hence the other leg in this triangle is $\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{4}}$ and this is therefore the radius of the circle of intersection.  So the circumference is $2\pi\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{4}}$.

Answer (score 1):

From central section containg unit sphere centers,

$ r^2 = 1^2 -(x/2)^2, r= \sqrt{1- x^2/4}$ , circumference = $ 2 \pi r $

[image: CentralSection]